# Does console logging ($log.log) slow down angular applications?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to optimize my SPA, I have followed all of the normal steps regarding binding, ng-repeat, watches, reducing http calls, minification, concatenation,etc.  My question is regarding console logging.  I currently write a fair amount to the console.  My application will typically output 400-500 msgs during use.  Which I have used to debugging purposes.  Do I need to strip $log.log references and console.log calls?  Or does it simply check if console log is available and if not then it does nothing.  So the overhead of the call will be diminimus?

Comment: Not really very helpful.  I know how to debug.  Regardless or purpose of the logged events, the question remains of overhead.

Comment: I would guess it depends on the timespan covering those 400-500 messages, and what your performance criteria are.